# Save multiple media pictures for a value in database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, model, fastapi

I have a Table called **property** that accepts a **contains** column which refers to **propertyContains** table, then *propertyContains* will have a **media** column which refers to **media** table. i have no idea if i am storing the images the right way and i am wondering if there is any better/more efficient ways.

my code

```
class Property(Base):
    __tablename__ = "property"

    property_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("propertyOwner.user_id"))
    title = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)

    Location = Column(String)
    rented = Column(Boolean)
    rented_by = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("client.client_id"))

    contains = relationship("PropertyContains", back_populates="contains_owner")
    owner = relationship("Owner", back_populates="properties")

    date = Column(Date, default=func.now())

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True




class Media(Base):
    __tablename__ = "media"
    media_id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True, index=True)


    media1 = Column(LargeBinary)
    media2 = Column(LargeBinary)
    media3 = Column(LargeBinary)

    media_owner = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('propertyContains.property_contains_id', ondelete="CASCADE"))

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

class PropertyContains(Base):
    __tablename__ = "propertyContains"
    property_contains_id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True, index=True)
    property_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("property.property_id"))
    # media_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("media.media_id"))
    bed_rooms = Column(Integer)
    media = relationship("Media", backref="media", passive_deletes=True)

    contains_owner = relationship("Property", back_populates="contains")

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

please keep in note that i am a beginner <3.

Comment: Storing media like that in data in the database is not common or good practice as far as I know, storing media location (s3 URI, path, etc) is more common.

Comment: like storing them in my server then get the image by path??

Comment: Correct, you store the location and when you want to give/display the media you l can load it from the location or pass the location directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the good practice is to just save the image in your server and save the path.

Comment: if you have a source for this, it might be a good idea to include relevant recommendations?